# Meteor/Iron Router - When/Where to run JS to swap to WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to figure out where is the best place to run a jQuery plugin that replaces a textarea (with a reactive value). It needs to be called after the textarea has been assigned the value.

I've tried various places. The most correct place I've tried seems to be in the templates `onAfterAction` callback, in a `Meteor.defer`. This works about 95% of the time.

Something like this:

```
MyController = RouteController.extend({
     waitOn:  function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('post', this.params._id);
     },
     onAfterAction: function () {
        Meteor.defer(function () {
            $('.make-wysiwyg').wysiwyg();
        });
    }
});
```

However, occasionally it doesn't. If I start bouncing between posts really quick, occasionally one will apparently run before the `textarea` has data and fail to display property (it'll be empty, because it needs the value before `wysiwyg()` is called).

I've eliminated the `wysiwyg()` function itself as the culprit by replacing that line with:

```
$('.make-wysiwyg').each(function () {console.log($(this).val())});
```

And I can clearly see every so often it'll print empty value fields for no apparent reason.

I'm not sure if the template or `publish()` function could be a culprit, so I'll supply them as well.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Template:

```
<template name="adminPostsEdit">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>
    <form id="edit-post" class="{{isNewClass}}" method="post">
        <label for="post-title">Title</label>
        <input id="post-title" value="{{post.title}}">
        <label for="post-slug">Slug</label>
        <input id="post-slug" value="{{post.slug}}">
        <label for="post-content">Content</label>
        <textarea id="post-content" class="make-wysiwyg">{{post.content}}</textarea>
        <label for="post-excerpt">Excerpt</label>
        <textarea id="post-excerpt" class="make-wysiwyg">{{post.excerpt}}</textarea>
        {{#if post.published}}
        <button value="save">Save</button>
        <button value="unpublish">Unpublish</button>
        {{else}}
        <button value="save">Save Draft</button>
        <button value="publish">Publish</button>
        {{/if}}
        <button value="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

`publish()`:

```
Meteor.publish('post', function (id) {
    return Posts.find({_id: id});
});
```

Helpers:

```
Template.adminPostsEdit.helpers({
    post: function () {
        return Posts.findOne();
    },
    isNewClass: function () {
        return !this.id ? 'new' : '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do that in the template's render function.

```
Template.adminPostsEdit.rendered = function() {
    $('.make-wysiwyg').wysiwyg();
})
```